# How to reduce the cyclomatic complexity of this function?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that takes a timestamp in epoch (like `1517073001`) and returns the time that has passed since then in a simple format like "2 hours ago" (not further verbosity like "2 hours, 31 minutes and 15 seconds ago").

The function works as intended but JSHint complains about using too many statements (30) and its cyclomatic complexity being too high (12). I was wondering what could be a way to improve these two aspects.

This is the function:

```js
function msToTime(epoch) {
  var previous = new Date(epoch * 1000);
  var current = Math.floor(new Date().getTime());
  var ms = current - previous;
  var years = parseInt((ms / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 12)).toFixed(20), 10);
  var months = parseInt((ms / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30) % 12).toFixed(20), 10);
  var days = parseInt((ms / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) % 30).toFixed(20), 10);
  var hours = parseInt((ms / (1000 * 60 * 60) % 24).toFixed(20), 10);
  var minutes = parseInt(ms / (1000 * 60) % 60, 10);
  var seconds = parseInt(ms / 1000 % 60, 10);
  var formatted = '';

  if (years > 0) {
    if (years > 1) {
      formatted = years + ' years ago';
    } else {
      formatted = years + ' year ago';
    }
  } else if (months > 0) {
    if (months > 1) {
      formatted = months + ' months ago';
    } else {
      formatted = months + ' month ago';
    }
  } else if (days > 0) {
    if (days > 1) {
      formatted = days + ' days ago';
    } else {
      formatted = days + ' day ago';
    }
  } else if (hours > 0) {
    if (hours > 1) {
      formatted = hours + ' hours ago';
    } else {
      formatted = hours + ' hour ago';
    }
  } else if (minutes > 0) {
    if (minutes > 1) {
      formatted = minutes + ' minutes ago';
    } else {
      formatted = minutes + ' minute ago';
    }
  } else {
    if (seconds > 1) {
      formatted = seconds + ' seconds ago';
    } else {
      formatted = seconds + ' second ago';
    }
  }

  return formatted;
}

var div = document.getElementById('time');
div.innerHTML = msToTime(1517073001);
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: You could use ternary operators instead your inner `if...else` conditions. For your outer `if...else if` you could use `switch(true)`.

Comment: Why not simply `Math.floor(n)` instead of `parseInt(n.toFixed(20), 10)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another version optimized for divs and modules operations

```
function msToTime(epoch) {
    var value = (Math.floor(new Date().getTime()) - new Date(epoch * 1000)) / 1000;

    var time_factors = [['second', 60], ['minute', 60], ['hour', 24], ['day', 30], ['month', 12], ['year', NaN]];

    for (factor of time_factors) {

        if (value < factor[1] || isNaN(factor[1])) {
            var t = Math.floor(value);
            return t + ' ' + (t > 1 ? factor[0] + 's' : factor[0]) + ' ago';
        }
        value /= factor[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the logic you used here. Very short and clean code. I edited it a bit and reduced its cyclomatic complexity even more to just 3 (also this one doesn't require ES6+): https://jsfiddle.net/s4euy0ue/2/

Answer (score 2):

Replacing `if...else if...else if...` by `switch (true)` and putting the building of singular or plural to a function:

```js
function msToTime(epoch) {
  let previous = new Date(epoch * 1000);
  let current = Math.floor(new Date().getTime());
  let ms = current - previous;
  let years = parseInt((ms / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 12)).toFixed(20), 10);
  let months = parseInt((ms / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30) % 12).toFixed(20), 10);
  let days = parseInt((ms / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) % 30).toFixed(20), 10);
  let hours = parseInt((ms / (1000 * 60 * 60) % 24).toFixed(20), 10);
  let minutes = parseInt(ms / (1000 * 60) % 60, 10);
  let seconds = parseInt(ms / 1000 % 60, 10);
  let formatted = '';

  function timeAgo(count, word) {
    return `${count} ${(count === 1 ? word : word + 's')} ago`
  }
  
  switch (true) {
  case years > 0: 
    formatted = timeAgo(years, 'year')
    break
  case months > 0: 
    formatted = timeAgo(months, 'month')
    break
  case days > 0: 
    formatted = timeAgo(days, 'day')
    break
  case hours > 0: 
    formatted = timeAgo(hours, 'hour')
    break
  case minutes > 0: 
    formatted = timeAgo(minutes, 'minute')
    break
  default: 
    formatted = timeAgo(seconds, 'second')
  }

  return formatted;
}

time.innerHTML = msToTime(1517073001);
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Defining the date as array and iterating over it has decreased the Cyclomatic complexity number to 4(!), with only 12 statements.

```js
  function msToTime(epoch) {
    var previous = new Date(epoch * 1000);
    var current = Math.floor(new Date().getTime());
    var ms = current - previous;
    var formatted = '';
    var completeDate = [
      ['year', parseInt((ms / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 12)).toFixed(20), 10)],
      ['month', parseInt((ms / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30) % 12).toFixed(20), 10)],
      ['day', parseInt((ms / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) % 30).toFixed(20), 10)],
      ['hour', parseInt((ms / (1000 * 60 * 60) % 24).toFixed(20), 10)],
      ['minute', parseInt(ms / (1000 * 60) % 60, 10)],
      ['second', parseInt(ms / 1000 % 60, 10)]
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < completeDate.length; i++) {
      var amount = completeDate[i][1];
      if (amount > 0) {
        var unit = completeDate[i][0];
        formatted = amount + ' ' + (amount > 1 ? unit + 's' : unit) + ' ago';
        break;
      }
    }

    return formatted;
  }

  var div = document.getElementById('time');
  div.innerHTML = msToTime(1517073001);
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Thank you, @connexo, for the important advice!

Comment: Be aware that when you iterate over properties of an object, order is not guaranteed.

Comment: @connexo Thank you! This IS a very important piece of information. I've edited my answer, to prevent this situation.

Comment: I liked this method too. A further simplified version of it: https://jsfiddle.net/s4euy0ue/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
  function msToTime (epoch) {
    var previous = new Date(epoch * 1000);
    var current = Math.floor(new Date().getTime());
    var ms = current - previous;
    var years = parseInt((ms / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 12)).toFixed(20), 10);
    var months = parseInt((ms / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30) % 12).toFixed(20), 10);
    var days = parseInt((ms / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) % 30).toFixed(20), 10);
    var hours = parseInt((ms / (1000 * 60 * 60) % 24).toFixed(20), 10);
    var minutes = parseInt(ms / (1000 * 60) % 60, 10);
    var seconds = parseInt(ms / 1000 % 60, 10);
    var formatted = '';

    if (years > 0) {
        formatted = years > 1 ? years + ' years ago' : years + ' year ago';

    } else if (months > 0) {
        formatted = months > 1 ? ' months ago' :  ' month ago';
    } else if (days > 0) {
        formatted = days > 1 ? ' days ago' :  ' day ago';
    } else if (hours > 0) {
      formatted = hours > 1 ? ' hours ago' :  ' hour ago';
    } else if (minutes > 0) {
      formatted = minutes > 1 ? ' minutes ago' :  ' minute ago';
    } else {
      formatted = seconds > 1 ? ' seconds ago' :  ' second ago';
    }

    return formatted;
  }

  var div = document.getElementById('time');
  div.innerHTML = msToTime(1417073002);
```

I have used JS ternary operator to shorten you code. Hope it helps.

Comment: The conditions need to be `> 1`

Comment: Substituting an `if` for a ternary expression doesn't change the cyclomatic complexity of a function.